# ipython reads from Enthought library

Tags: python, ipython, enthought, anaconda

I've installed anaconda and sklearn.  I can use the sklearn library when I'm using spyder from the anaconda package, but when I try to do the same in iPython I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jamesbkel/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_fblas.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jamesbkel/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_fblas.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Spyder is accessing the correct python library, but iPython is not, right?  How do I link iPython to the correct library?

Comment: What's in your .bash_profile?

Comment: The problem is most likely that your PYTHONPATH and your PATH are being set to include the path to Canopy at the beginning.  If you do a "which ipython", you'll probably see that it's the Canopy one.  If you want to use Anaconda, you'll need to edit your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc, and go to the end, and comment out the lines that are putting Canopy on the path.

Comment: On OS X it is likely `~/.profile`.

Comment: When do a "which python", terminal says that it's linked to anaconda, which is what I'd like: "/Users/jamesbkel/anaconda/bin/python".  This is probably why Spyder is working for me, at least.

Comment: Commenting out the Canopy path was the fix.  Thanks, Peter!